# What is the function of setting a for loop's test condition to a pointer

Tags: c

I'm having a little difficulty trying to understand what setting a for loop's test condition to a pointer does exactly, or even setting it to a variable value without any comparison.  One code example I'm working with on my homework is:

```
int f ( char *s, char *t) {
  char *p1, *p2;
  for (p1 = s; *p1; p1++) {
    for (p2 = t; *p2; p2++)
      if (*p1==*p2) break;
    if (*p2 == ‘\0’) break;
  }
return p1-s;
}
```

I'm not looking for an explanation of the function, more of just an explanation of the test condition on the two for loops.

Comment: `*p1` and `*p2` aren't pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for (p1 = s; *p1; p1++) {
  for (p2 = t; *p2; p2++) {
```

It's equivalent to comparing `*p1` and `*p2` to NUL (`\0`). The loops will terminate when the strings' NUL terminators are reached.

```
for (p1 = s; *p1 != '\0'; p1++) {
  for (p2 = t; *p2 != '\0'; p2++) {
```

You can use this shorthand in `if` and `while` statements as well, and for other types. Leaving out the condition checks the variable against the default zero value for its type: `'\0'` for characters, `0` for integers, `0.0f` or `0.0` for floats and doubles, `NULL` for pointers.

```
p = malloc(n);
if (p) {
    // if p is not null
}

int len = strlen(s);
while (len--) {
    // loop until len reaches 0
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`for (p1 = s; *p1; p1++)` continues to execute the loop while `*p1` is true, i.e., while the character value at address `p1` is nonzero, i.e., while `p1` is not pointing to a NUL byte.

Comment: +1 Good answer. This is due to the way a for loop is transformed into assembly - look it up user2281043 :)

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought it did but I wanted a second opinion

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with "the way a for loop is transformed into assembly", it's a matter of how the language is defined.

Answer (score -1):

Each character in the outer loop:

```
for (p1 = s; *p1; p1++) {
}
```

is tested character per character against the inner loop using pointer arithmetic and if there is match then break

```
for (p2 = t; *p2; p2++)
  if (*p1==*p2) break;
```

End of character or is NULL for inner loop then break from the loop also

```
if (*p2 == ‘\0’) break;
```